# Load php files into layout template?

Tags: php

I'm working on my first php site, I'm running into an issue I can't see to figure out. I'm trying to have one php page that contains my structure, and others that inject their html inside, while retaining url changes so I can still direct link pages.

So far this is what I'm doing, but it doesn't seem efficient:

**index.php**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <?php include("head.php"); ?>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Navigation header -->
            <?php include("navigation.php"); ?>

            <!-- Main container -->
            <div id="MainContainer">
                <?php include("home.php"); ?>
            </div>

            <!-- Footer -->
            <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**about.php**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <?php include("head.php"); ?>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Navigation header -->
            <?php include("navigation.php"); ?>

            <!-- Main container -->
            <div id="MainContainer">
                About me!
            </div>

            <!-- Footer -->
            <?php include("footer.php");  ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This feels totally wrong, if I ever want to change my container class, or change the structure, I now have to do it in two places instead of one.

In ASP.net MVC I would have a Layout_Head.cshtml file that would contain my HTML structure and inside I can render views from different pages, the url changes but the layout is always rendered first and then the controller/actions take care of injecting the html of the needed views.

How do I replicate that in PHP?

Comment: Why don't you put the `body` and `#container` tags inside the `head.php` file? You cannot compare ASP.net MVC to PHP. PHP is a language, ASP.NET MVC is a framework. If you want MVC, use a framework like Codeigniter.

Comment: I understand it's not the same, I was merely trying to explain how I do it usually :) as for putting the body and #container in the head.php, when I load the about.php how to I tell it to load the data in the #container?

Comment: You don't tell it to load anything; php includes simply echo out data as if you had've put the code there yourself. So your header file contains the starting HTML and any other wrappers, and the footer file contains the ending body/html tags.

Comment: I've added an answer to explain this in more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually people use php includes for templating more like this:

**header.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
```

**footer.php**

```
    </div> <!-- .container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**about.php**

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
  ... content goes here ...
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

This is so you don't need to continuously repeat the start/end tags on every template you make.

Comment: Oh I see... I was trying to have just one file that contained the opening and closing tags (header and footer merged into one) and then injecting the data in... that makes more sense now! Thanks!

Comment: @LanFeusT Yeah having layouts makes more sense, however PHP includes just don't support that kind of behaviour. When I started using layouts in Rails I found it a lot more powerful than PHP includes. Many PHP frameworks (eg, Wordpress), still use includes rather than layouts.